# Built a power supply but output isn't smooth enough?

Tags: power-supply, digital-logic, buck

I built an ac to dc power supply using the lm2576t. I have a full wave rectifier and a filtering capactor going into the lm2576t. The configuration I used for the lm2576t is the one on the first page. The output measures 4.97V dc but looks  messy on an oscope. I tried plugging my power supply into my digital timer circuit but it ends up timing fast. I figure it's due to the messy output from my power supply. It works perfectly with a battery pack. I also used it to power my microcontroller project but it doesn't work like it does running off a battery pack. Do you have any suggestions? Attached is the datasheet for it below.
http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/405/lm2576-405253.pdf

**update:**

Rebuilt my power supply on a prototype board and soldered all the components. All good now!

Comment: Is this a PCBA or protoboard/breadboard build? Also maybe post a pic of the output from the scope so we can see just how messy it is.

Comment: Post what you are seeing in the scope. Are you using all the recommended values in the datasheet?

Comment: I built it on a breadboard. I'm using all the recommended values on the first page of that datasheet. I have 120vac=>transformer=>full bridge rectifier=>filtering cap=>buck converter ic components. I'll snap a pic of the output tomorrow. I thought about putting a filtering cap at the output of the buck converter but there's already a 1000uf there...

Comment: What's the transformer output? What size and type is the input capacitor? What's the output load current? BTW protoboard type breadboards are often problematic for these types of circuits.

Comment: 1000 uF at the output of a LM25xx is excessive and probably the source of your problem.

Comment: @pc9460 I asked about the build because like gsills said, switching regulators usually don't work well on breadboards/protoboards because of the switching currents and grounding considerations. The switching circuit layout is important for optimal performance.

Comment: The LM25xx should be in www.badbeetles.com   but it hasnt appeared yet.

Comment: The filtering cap is 6000uF from the calculations I did based off the notes that my professor gave us. The transformer I'm using is from radioshack that takes 120vac to 12v center tapped. I can't find it anymore on the website.

Comment: I attached the output on the oscope above.

Comment: I honestly think your first step should be to rebuild the switcher circuit on stripboard, keeping in mind to keep the switching node small (it's really noisy) and keep the ground return paths short and low-impedance. (no wires, just fat traces and solder jumpers if necessary)

Comment: You would also need to add a local input capacitor if you locate the switcher on another board to compensate for the inductance of the wires that connect back to your offline supply.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely [aren't measuring the ripple correctly](http://www.eetimes.com/document.asp?doc_id=1273282). That's not to say that there isn't *some* noise on the output, but common-mode pollution of the scope measurement due to ground-lead pickup is very common when you're dealing with switching converters.

You need to use a probe with a very short ground lead and need to have bandwidth limiting enabled on your scope channel.

Please update your question with the results of this experiment (as well as a photo of your breadboard) and we can proceed further.

Comment: This is likely the cause, this is how you should measure the output from the regulator http://goo.gl/WfAL3t

Comment: Refer to the hyperlinked article. Use a short-ground probe and measure directly across the leads of your output capacitor. Also turn on BWL on your scope (20 MHz).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your filter capacitor after the full-wave bridge is much too small.

Take your capacitor load current, your maximum allowed ripple voltage, and then use the formula:

C = Iload / (fline * Vripple)

where Iload is load current of the filter capacitor, fline is 2x your AC line frequency, and Vripple is the peak-to-peak voltage.

Here's an example: your line frequency is 60 Hz, your filtered AC at the full-wave bridge peaks at 16V and you want lowest part of the dip to be 12V. This means your ripple voltage is 4V. And let's say the filter cap has to supply 1 Amp to the LM2576. Using the formula, C = 1.0 Amp / (120 Hz * 4 Volts) = 2,000 uF.

So in this example, you would need a 2,000 uF filter capacitor (with 20V or 25V rating). If you only rely on the 100 uF in the design example then the LM2576 is starved for voltage and is shutting down 120 times per second! Hope that helps.

Comment: I sized a filtering cap of 6000uF using equations that had in my notes from my professor.

Comment: Ah, now that you added the scope photo, it is obvious that you are getting a lot of switching noise in your output. Take a look at Figure 21 and 22 in the datasheet and the text about how layout is very critical. The ground return of the output cap must be very strongly connected to the input cap and both must be connected strongly to the GND of the LM2576 and the catch diode. Upload a photo of your prototype also so we can see the layout and construction. Thanks.

Comment: I've uploaded a photo of my layout. You can't see the transformer and the diode in the photo but they are there. The two big caps are 12000uF added in series to make a 6000uF filtering cap.