# When is a uC power supply "smooth enough" e.g. when some noisy (inductive, switch) load is around?

Tags: power-supply, power, pwm, crosstalk

I'm building a battery/solar-powered 12V thingy that has an ESP32 microcontroller (5V generated from the 12V) and PWMs a 12V pump. The pump produces all sorts of voltage spikes on the 12V, and I'm trying to keep those as far apart from the ESP32's 5V power as possible with assorted capacitors and separate wiring.

(Note: I have read and am applying https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/202530/110207)

When in my process should I declare it to be "good enough"? The goal is that the ESP32 won't crash on me or burn out or such. Is there a rule of thumb? What kind of noise on 5V power is normal and acceptable for microcontrollers?

Comment: the rule of thumb is to give it what the data-sheet says it wants.

Answer (score 2):

If the MCU has an ADC to measure some sensors, then you should assume the ADC ability to reject VDD trash is zero.

That is, during most-significan-bit decisions, a 100 millivolt spike into your +5 regulator will probably produce 100mV output, because LDOs just cannot work fast enough to prevent input spikes from becoming output spikes. And your ADC likely will make a 100 millivolt error in quantizing the sensor voltage. Is that OK?

Your question then becomes: how much upsetting of measurements will I tolerate? and you
can use L+C filtering between the +12v and the +5 regulator.

100 uH in the +12v line to regulator, with 100uF shunting input to regulator to GND, with 1 ohm resistor in **SERIES** with 100 uH, might work.

================================ edit

[ I'd previously had the 1 ohm Rdampen in parallel with inductor, to avoid consuming DC headroom; but with 12-5 = 7 volts headroom, lets have the resistor be in series, for even better 2-pole attenuation.

Comment: Who says an ADC is even being used?

Comment: true, but the implication is that this is likely the only issue he'd encounter from a functioning microcontroller circuit with a noisy power supply

Comment: I will try that L+R combo, but currently waiting for parts. I'm amateur enough that I don't have many L's handy ...